# pg_ctl won't start postgres

Tags: postgresql, startup

I'm new to PostgreSQL.  Although I could access a localhost database either with PGAdminIII or psql (eg `sudo -u postgres psql mydb`), I've not been able to connect from Dart.  I think my difficulties are with Postgres.

Previously when I've used Postgres (Windows 10) I could start the server with

```
pg_ctl start -l ~/pglog.txt
```

Now (ubuntu 16.04), this same command gives me this error:

```
pg_ctl: could not open PID file 
    "/var/lib/postgresql/9.5/main/postmaster.pid": Permission denied*
```

(PGDATA is set to /var/lib/postgresql/9.5/main)
Folder *main* has user/group of *postgres/postgres* as does it's parent, postgresql.  /*var/lib* has owner/group *root/root*.

If I run the same command as the postgres user (su -c 'pg_ctl start -l ~/pglog' postgres), after entering the password, the error message is:

```
su: Authentication failure
```

(I'm sure I have the pw correct, but is there some way to check/change/confirm that...bearing in mind that I now can't get the server running.)

The bin folder is in my path. There are postmaster.pid and postgresql.conf files in the data directory.

I have changed authentication for local users in pg_hba.conf to md5 rather than peer.

I think I installed postgresql with this command:

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql postgresql-contrib
```

ref (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PostgreSQL).

Having changed a few permissions, then, as far as I can tell, changed them back again, the server no longer runs on bootup.  That is, I can now no longer connect with either PGAdminIII or psql.  I've not been able to find out how it would have started previously.

I feel sure that I have some permissions incorrect?  Other suggested topics on StackOverflow have not been sufficient to allow me to resolve this.  One answer is the following:

> Sounds like a permission problem on the data directory. Did you check if the postgres (operating system) user has full access to /usr/local/pgsql/data and all sub-directories?*

Another answer included:

> "Permission denied" is usually a problem with the access rights on the data directory. Make sure the postgres user account has full access to /usr/local/pgsql/data

8 March: 
Thanks Roman.  Using your suggested command I get

```
sudo: pg_ctl: command not found
```

But running without sudo I got the following promising message (which is weird given that that's essentially what I was using before but with no response):

```
pg_ctl start -l /tmp/pglog.txt
server starting
```

Notwithstanding this, I still don't think the server is running - this is the message from either PGAdmin3 or psql.

Evan, thank you also. The latter gives no error and returns to the prompt after perhaps 2 seconds - so it appears to be doing something.  But trying to connect with PGAdmin3 or psql still indicates that no server is listening.  Eg:

```
psql postgres
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

I've checked postgres.conf and see that the port seems to be correct.

Comment: sudo pg_ctl start -l /tmp/pglog.txt

Comment: @Trevor you need to comment on the answer not just silently update the question so we can't see it. Try running `ls /var/run/postgresql/*PGSQL*`

Answer (score 2):

In Ubuntu you don't start PostgreSQL with `pg_ctl`. You can, but don't. Instead, use this

```
sudo service postgresql start
```

`su -c` will only work if you enable the root account. Don't do that. Instead, use `sudo`.

[*See my answer here for how to get up and running on Ubuntu*](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/160816/2639)

Comment: on the latest ubuntu you need to run `sudo service postgresql start` (different order of arguments)

Comment: Typoed that. It's Fixed.

Comment: can you elaborate on the why part? thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to be postgres user to be able to start postgres with pg_ctl. So I guess your command should be something like that (remember that it's possible that postgres user $PATH is not set properly, that's why I added the complete binary path) :

```
sudo -u postgres /usr/lib/postgresql/9.5/bin/pg_ctl start -l ~/pglog.txt
```

(If you're using Ubuntu, you can use the Debian Postgres perl wrappers which are really great. https://manpages.debian.org/jessie/postgresql-common/index.html)